# How to code a default namespace and a namespace with a prefix for single XML element in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I want my xml element as follows

```
<exElement xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

I used the following code

```
rootElement.setAttributeNS("urn:hl7-org:v3", "xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```

And gives me the Element as follows which is different than what i want.

```
<exElement xmlns:ns0="urn:hl7-org:v3" xsi:ns1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Can anyone please correct my code if there is an issue? Help will be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

I am using [xom](http://www.xom.nu/) library for `XML-manipulation` :

```
Element root = new Element("exElement");
root.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
root.setNamespaceURI("urn:hl7-org:v3");

Document document = new Document(root);
System.out.println("XML :: " + document.toXML());
```

that's working fine for me & give me result :

```
XML :: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<exElement xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

still some problem post me.